# How to Address a Folder in my java Project?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to upload pictures in my source project. It works when I address  desktop but I don't know How to address In my source

```
for(FileItem item : items){                        
  File upDir = new File("/SliderManagment2/uppic");
  File file = File.createTempFile("img", ".png" , upDir);
  item.write(file);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> For Microsoft Windows platforms, the prefix of a pathname that
>   contains a drive specifier consists of the drive letter followed by
>   ":" and possibly followed by "\" if the pathname is absolute. The
>   prefix of a UNC pathname is "\\"; the hostname and the share name
>   are the first two names in the name sequence. A relative pathname that
>   does not specify a drive has no prefix.